# Validity of Navigo weekly pass

Tags: trains, public-transport, paris

I'm looking for an official source which says which days are covered by a weekly pass for the Paris metro (on a Navigo).  I can find plenty of unofficial sources which say that the pass is valid Monday through Sunday (i.e. it includes the weekend following the week in question, but not the weekend before).  The official webpage:
https://www.ratp.fr/en/titres-et-tarifs/navigo-monthly-and-weekly-travel-passes
is annoyingly vague.  It also seems to imply that a weekly pass *is* valid both weekends adjacent to the week in question:

> You may use all public transport in the Île-de-France region regardless of the zones specified on your travel pass: all weekend long, from Saturday, 12 a.m., through Sunday 11:59 p.m.

The French version doesn't seem to be any clearer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wow, the current incarnation RATP website is indeed missing a lot of information. (The French version used to be a lot better, and the English version used to completely omit commuter passes. Looks like they've now aligned the version, but they've removed a lot of information.)

RATP is just one of the agencies that run public transport in the Paris area, so you can also look for information in other places such [Navigo](http://www.navigo.fr/) (agency that manages the Navigo pass, [French only](http://www.navigo.fr/titres/le-forfait-navigo-semaine-presentation/)) or [SNCF Transilien](https://www.transilien.com/) (the agency that runs the suburban trains, [French](https://www.transilien.com/fr/page-editoriale/utiliser-la-carte-navigo-decouverte) and [English](https://www.transilien.com/en/page-editoriale/using-the-navigo-decouverte-card)). Both correctly state that **a Navigo weekly pass is valid from Monday to Sunday** (and likewise a Navigo monthly pass is valid from the first to the last day of a calendar month).

The most official source is the [terms of service](http://www.navigo.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/CGVU-Forfait-Navigo-mois-semaine.pdf) (French only, not searchable or accessible to screen readers). The official rules state that the pass is valid from Monday 0:00 to Sunday 23:59. The cutoff time is the time when you enter the metro or heavy rail network, or the time when you board a bus or tram, you can finish the last leg of your journey after midnight. There's an exception for the night buses (Noctilien): on Noctilien services, the pass is valid both on the Monday morning at the end of the validity period and as the Monday morning at the beginning of the validity period.

The addendum about zones on the week-end (“*dézonage*”) does not apply to weekly passes, only to monthly passes. If you have a 2-zone weekly pass, it's only valid in these two zones, period. If you have an all-zone weekly pass, it's valid throughout the Île-de-France region.

Comment: Minor question : Concerning the end of validity (Noctilien put aside), it is explicitly mentioned (in the ToS) that it is valid until _sunday 23:59, time of entrance in the network _. I would consider that it means you cannot enter the network monday at 00:30 but you can use a connection. I don't know wether it means that automatic entrance gates will not open after 23:59

Comment: @audionuma Right, the TOS state that 00:00 is the cutoff time for entering the network (i.e. for validating the ticket at an entrance gate at a metro or heavy rail station, or when boarding a bus or tram). That would be the time when the validators stop accepting the pass. I thought that the cutoff time was the end of service. It's possible that the rules have changed in the past few years.

Comment: Note that if you switch from metro to RER you will go through validators at that point. Have to admit I’m surprised by the midnight cut-off...

Comment: Is a RER validator smart enough to know that the journey began before 23:59 ?

Comment: @audionuma I don't know if you're allowed to transfer between the metro and the RER after 23:59 on Sunday. The rules state that the relevant time is “the time of validation on entrance of the chosen mode of transportation”, but they don't define whether metro and RER/suburban counts as a single mode of transportation for this purpose.

Comment: i've been looking for this answer for a year and thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

I live in Paris and I can say that the weekly pass last from Monday to Sunday so if you buy it on Tuesday you will be able to use it until Sunday only and not the day after (Monday).